# Using Top to get only the first row, but from multiple records in a subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, one with customers and one with payments

Need the most recent payment from customers with specific criteria.  Created a query for that specific_criteria)

```
select top 1 *
from payments
where id in (select id from specific_criteria);
```

Obviously, that only returns one row.

I can't actually write VB code in this database to do it.

Looking for some SQL code that will get the most recent payment per customer.

Comment: Top n per group : support.microsoft.com/kb/153747.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.*,
       p.*
FROM Customers c
     INNER JOIN
     Payments p ON p.Customer_ID=c.ID
WHERE p.ID IN (SELECT p2.ID FROM
               (SELECT p1.ID, MAX(p1.payment_date)
               FROM Payments p1
               GROUP BY p1.ID) AS p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
select c.*, (
    select top 1 p.*
    from payments p
    where p.customer_id = c.id
    order by p.payment_date desc )
from customers c
where customer_critera
```